# Controller File Updated on Nginx But Server still serves old content

Tags: node.js, nginx

I recently made some changes to one of my controllers on my nodejs application, the changes work fine locally, but when I deploy to the production server, though the changes reflect in the code on the server, it still serves the old version of the file. Am I missing out something?

I've tried restarting the server using

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Result stays the same.
Also tried redeploying, even tried to break the code and push it like that, yet all I get is the same old version. Any solution?

P.S I use PM2 in starting the app

Comment: Are you using NGINX as a reverse-proxy? If so you need to start your node server instead NGINX

Comment: I'm using pm2. Thing is, this is not the first time I'm deploying, it's been working fine for a long while now, don't know what could be wrong

Comment: Might be a long shot, but if you package bundle you application using something like webpack it might be the browser that has cached the bundle.js file. To quickly check if that is the case, browse your application in a private browser window - if it serves the new version now you know that browser caching is your problem.

Comment: @Misantorp just tried that, still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it! Turns out I had to restart pm2 and not nginx. So I just ran

```
pm2 reload APP_NAME
```

And it updates

P.S You can know what APP_NAME is by running `pm2 list`